# Slice dataframe based on boolean function

Tags: pandas

I have D.F. named **test**:

```
      December January    Rating
    0   35.00   35.00      1star
    1   0.00    100.00     2star
    2   38.71   28.46      3star
    3   74.32   61.32      4star
    4   65.39   66.505     3star
```

I want to filter rows **except the last column**, based on this boolean: `test[test<test.mean()]`
Note that mean() value will be different for each column.

Result is :

```
  December  January  Rating
0   35.00   35.00     NaN
1   0.00    NaN       NaN
2   38.71   28.46     NaN
3   NaN     NaN       NaN
4   NaN     NaN       NaN
```

Desired output:

```
     December January     Rating
    0   35.00   35.00     1star
    1   0.00    NaN       2star
    2   38.71   28.46     3star
    3   NaN     NaN       4star
    4   NaN     NaN       3star
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `mean` and `where` `lt` here is `<`

```
df[['December','January']]=df[['December','January']].where(df.lt(df.mean()))
df
Out[77]: 
   December  January Rating
0     35.00    35.00  1star
1      0.00      NaN  2star
2     38.71    28.46  3star
3       NaN      NaN  4star
4       NaN      NaN  3star
```